# In magento 2 How to add custom.js

Tags: magento2, javascript

I want to add `custom.js` file in Magento 2. I have installed comeback theme.
custom.js file location: `\app\design\frontend\Emthemes\comeback\default\web\js\custom.js`

Please tell me how to add this `custom.js` file in magento

Answer (score 2):

Add `<script src="js/custom.js"/>` In Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml in `<head>` section.

OR

You need to add this js name in requirejs-config.js file .

Like goto :: \app\design\frontend\Emthemes\comeback\default\requirejs-config.js

add this in requirejs-config.js ::

```
var config = {  map: {
    "*": {
        ......
        'anyname' : 'js/custom.js',
        ......
    }
},
paths:  {
    ....
},
"shim": {
  ...
  },deps: [    
   ...
]  };
```

then after run the command to deploy the pub static folder.

```
sudo bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add it to:

```
/app/design/frontend/Emthemes/comeback/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml
```

Using the code

```
<link src="js/custom.js" />
```